# How to use as tuple[] parameter in Remix interface (solidity, smart-contract)

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

Contract - RaribleUserToken

Function: mint

I have problem with "fees" argument

My attempts:
['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 34]
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", 34]
'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 34
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", 34
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 34
etc

I only get errors...

> Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid tuple value (argument="tuple", value="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)
>
> transact to RaribleUserToken.mint errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 34]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)

[image: ddd]

Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;



library SafeMath {

   
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
       
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.
    */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        // uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return a / b;
    }

   
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

   
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}


contract CommonConstants {

    bytes4 constant internal ERC1155_ACCEPTED = 0xf23a6e61; // bytes4(keccak256("onERC1155Received(address,address,uint256,uint256,bytes)"))
    bytes4 constant internal ERC1155_BATCH_ACCEPTED = 0xbc197c81; // bytes4(keccak256("onERC1155BatchReceived(address,address,uint256[],uint256[],bytes)"))
}


interface ERC1155TokenReceiver {
   
    function onERC1155Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _id, uint256 _value, bytes calldata _data) external returns(bytes4);

   function onERC1155BatchReceived(address _operator, address _from, uint256[] calldata _ids, uint256[] calldata _values, bytes calldata _data) external returns(bytes4);
}


interface IERC165 {
   
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool);
}


contract IERC1155 is IERC165 {
    
    event TransferSingle(address indexed _operator, address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _id, uint256 _value);

   
    event TransferBatch(address indexed _operator, address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256[] _ids, uint256[] _values);

    
    event ApprovalForAll(address indexed _owner, address indexed _operator, bool _approved);

    
    event URI(string _value, uint256 indexed _id);

    
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _id, uint256 _value, bytes calldata _data) external;

    
    function safeBatchTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256[] calldata _ids, uint256[] calldata _values, bytes calldata _data) external;

    
    function balanceOf(address _owner, uint256 _id) external view returns (uint256);

  
    function balanceOfBatch(address[] calldata _owners, uint256[] calldata _ids) external view returns (uint256[] memory);

   
    function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external;

   
    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool);
}


contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
    /*
     * bytes4(keccak256('supportsInterface(bytes4)')) == 0x01ffc9a7
     */
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC165 = 0x01ffc9a7;

    /**
     * @dev Mapping of interface ids to whether or not it's supported.
     */
    mapping(bytes4 => bool) private _supportedInterfaces;

    constructor () internal {
        // Derived contracts need only register support for their own interfaces,
        // we register support for ERC165 itself here
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC165);
    }

   
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool) {
        return _supportedInterfaces[interfaceId];
    }

   
    function _registerInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) internal {
        require(interfaceId != 0xffffffff, "ERC165: invalid interface id");
        _supportedInterfaces[interfaceId] = true;
    }
}


library Address {
    
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        // According to EIP-1052, 0x0 is the value returned for not-yet created accounts
        // and 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 is returned
        // for accounts without code, i.e. `keccak256('')`
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }

   
    function toPayable(address account) internal pure returns (address payable) {
        return address(uint160(account));
    }

   
    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-call-value
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call.value(amount)("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
}

// A sample implementation of core ERC1155 function.
contract ERC1155 is IERC1155, ERC165, CommonConstants
{
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    // id => (owner => balance)
    mapping (uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) internal balances;

    // owner => (operator => approved)
    mapping (address => mapping(address => bool)) internal operatorApproval;

/////////////////////////////////////////// ERC165 //////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
        bytes4(keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,uint256,bytes)")) ^
        bytes4(keccak256("safeBatchTransferFrom(address,address,uint256[],uint256[],bytes)")) ^
        bytes4(keccak256("balanceOf(address,uint256)")) ^
        bytes4(keccak256("balanceOfBatch(address[],uint256[])")) ^
        bytes4(keccak256("setApprovalForAll(address,bool)")) ^
        bytes4(keccak256("isApprovedForAll(address,address)"));
    */
    bytes4 constant private INTERFACE_SIGNATURE_ERC1155 = 0xd9b67a26;

/////////////////////////////////////////// CONSTRUCTOR //////////////////////////////////////////

    constructor() public {
        _registerInterface(INTERFACE_SIGNATURE_ERC1155);
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////// ERC1155 //////////////////////////////////////////////

            function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _id, uint256 _value, bytes calldata _data) external {

        require(_to != address(0x0), "_to must be non-zero.");
        require(_from == msg.sender || operatorApproval[_from][msg.sender] == true, "Need operator approval for 3rd party transfers.");

        // SafeMath will throw with insuficient funds _from
        // or if _id is not valid (balance will be 0)
        balances[_id][_from] = balances[_id][_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_id][_to]   = _value.add(balances[_id][_to]);

        // MUST emit event
        emit TransferSingle(msg.sender, _from, _to, _id, _value);

        // Now that the balance is updated and the event was emitted,
        // call onERC1155Received if the destination is a contract.
        if (_to.isContract()) {
            _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck(msg.sender, _from, _to, _id, _value, _data);
        }
    }

    
    function safeBatchTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256[] calldata _ids, uint256[] calldata _values, bytes calldata _data) external {

        // MUST Throw on errors
        require(_to != address(0x0), "destination address must be non-zero.");
        require(_ids.length == _values.length, "_ids and _values array lenght must match.");
        require(_from == msg.sender || operatorApproval[_from][msg.sender] == true, "Need operator approval for 3rd party transfers.");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _ids.length; ++i) {
            uint256 id = _ids[i];
            uint256 value = _values[i];

            // SafeMath will throw with insuficient funds _from
            // or if _id is not valid (balance will be 0)
            balances[id][_from] = balances[id][_from].sub(value);
            balances[id][_to]   = value.add(balances[id][_to]);
        }

        // Note: instead of the below batch versions of event and acceptance check you MAY have emitted a TransferSingle
        // event and a subsequent call to _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck in above loop for each balance change instead.
        // Or emitted a TransferSingle event for each in the loop and then the single _doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck below.
        // However it is implemented the balance changes and events MUST match when a check (i.e. calling an external contract) is done.

        // MUST emit event
        emit TransferBatch(msg.sender, _from, _to, _ids, _values);

        // Now that the balances are updated and the events are emitted,
        // call onERC1155BatchReceived if the destination is a contract.
        if (_to.isContract()) {
            _doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck(msg.sender, _from, _to, _ids, _values, _data);
        }
    }

   
    function balanceOf(address _owner, uint256 _id) external view returns (uint256) {
        // The balance of any account can be calculated from the Transfer events history.
        // However, since we need to keep the balances to validate transfer request,
        // there is no extra cost to also privide a querry function.
        return balances[_id][_owner];
    }


   
    function balanceOfBatch(address[] calldata _owners, uint256[] calldata _ids) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {

        require(_owners.length == _ids.length);

        uint256[] memory balances_ = new uint256[](_owners.length);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i) {
            balances_[i] = balances[_ids[i]][_owners[i]];
        }

        return balances_;
    }

   
    function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external {
        operatorApproval[msg.sender][_operator] = _approved;
        emit ApprovalForAll(msg.sender, _operator, _approved);
    }

   
    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool) {
        return operatorApproval[_owner][_operator];
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////// Internal //////////////////////////////////////////////

    function _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck(address _operator, address _from, address _to, uint256 _id, uint256 _value, bytes memory _data) internal {

        


       
        require(ERC1155TokenReceiver(_to).onERC1155Received(_operator, _from, _id, _value, _data) == ERC1155_ACCEPTED, "contract returned an unknown value from onERC1155Received");
    }

    function _doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck(address _operator, address _from, address _to, uint256[] memory _ids, uint256[] memory _values, bytes memory _data) internal {

       

       
        require(ERC1155TokenReceiver(_to).onERC1155BatchReceived(_operator, _from, _ids, _values, _data) == ERC1155_BATCH_ACCEPTED, "contract returned an unknown value from onERC1155BatchReceived");
    }
}

library UintLibrary {
    function toString(uint256 _i) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
            bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
}

library StringLibrary {
    using UintLibrary for uint256;

    function append(string memory _a, string memory _b) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);
        bytes memory _bb = bytes(_b);
        bytes memory bab = new bytes(_ba.length + _bb.length);
        uint k = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) bab[k++] = _ba[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) bab[k++] = _bb[i];
        return string(bab);
    }

    function append(string memory _a, string memory _b, string memory _c) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);
        bytes memory _bb = bytes(_b);
        bytes memory _bc = bytes(_c);
        bytes memory bbb = new bytes(_ba.length + _bb.length + _bc.length);
        uint k = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) bbb[k++] = _ba[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) bbb[k++] = _bb[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bc.length; i++) bbb[k++] = _bc[i];
        return string(bbb);
    }

    function recover(string memory message, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) internal pure returns (address) {
        bytes memory msgBytes = bytes(message);
        bytes memory fullMessage = concat(
            bytes("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"),
            bytes(msgBytes.length.toString()),
            msgBytes,
            new bytes(0), new bytes(0), new bytes(0), new bytes(0)
        );
        return ecrecover(keccak256(fullMessage), v, r, s);
    }

    function concat(bytes memory _ba, bytes memory _bb, bytes memory _bc, bytes memory _bd, bytes memory _be, bytes memory _bf, bytes memory _bg) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory resultBytes = new bytes(_ba.length + _bb.length + _bc.length + _bd.length + _be.length + _bf.length + _bg.length);
        uint k = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _ba[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _bb[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bc.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _bc[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bd.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _bd[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _be.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _be[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bf.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _bf[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _bg.length; i++) resultBytes[k++] = _bg[i];
        return resultBytes;
    }
}

contract HasContractURI is ERC165 {

    string public contractURI;

    /*
     * bytes4(keccak256('contractURI()')) == 0xe8a3d485
     */
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_CONTRACT_URI = 0xe8a3d485;

    constructor(string memory _contractURI) public {
        contractURI = _contractURI;
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_CONTRACT_URI);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to set the contract URI
     * @param _contractURI string URI prefix to assign
     */
    function _setContractURI(string memory _contractURI) internal {
        contractURI = _contractURI;
    }
}

contract HasTokenURI {
    using StringLibrary for string;

    //Token URI prefix
    string public tokenURIPrefix;

    // Optional mapping for token URIs
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    constructor(string memory _tokenURIPrefix) public {
        tokenURIPrefix = _tokenURIPrefix;
    }

    
    function _tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (string memory) {
        return tokenURIPrefix.append(_tokenURIs[tokenId]);
    }


    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory uri) internal {
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = uri;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to set the token URI prefix.
     * @param _tokenURIPrefix string URI prefix to assign
     */
    function _setTokenURIPrefix(string memory _tokenURIPrefix) internal {
        tokenURIPrefix = _tokenURIPrefix;
    }

    function _clearTokenURI(uint256 tokenId) internal {
        if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
            delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        }
    }
}


contract Context {
    // Empty internal constructor, to prevent people from mistakenly deploying
    // an instance of this contract, which should be used via inheritance.
    constructor () internal { }
    // solhint-disable-previous-line no-empty-blocks

    function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}


contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor () internal {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns true if the caller is the current owner.
     */
    function isOwner() public view returns (bool) {
        return _msgSender() == _owner;
    }

  
    function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

  
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}

/**
    Note: The ERC-165 identifier for this interface is 0x0e89341c.
*/
interface IERC1155Metadata_URI {
   
    function uri(uint256 _id) external view returns (string memory);
}

/**
    Note: The ERC-165 identifier for this interface is 0x0e89341c.
*/
contract ERC1155Metadata_URI is IERC1155Metadata_URI, HasTokenURI {

    constructor(string memory _tokenURIPrefix) HasTokenURI(_tokenURIPrefix) public {

    }

    function uri(uint256 _id) external view returns (string memory) {
        return _tokenURI(_id);
    }
}

contract HasSecondarySaleFees is ERC165 {

    event SecondarySaleFees(uint256 tokenId, address[] recipients, uint[] bps);

    
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_FEES = 0xb7799584;

    constructor() public {
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_FEES);
    }

    function getFeeRecipients(uint256 id) public view returns (address payable[] memory);
    function getFeeBps(uint256 id) public view returns (uint[] memory);
}

contract ERC1155Base is HasSecondarySaleFees, Ownable, ERC1155Metadata_URI, HasContractURI, ERC1155 {

    struct Fee {
        address payable recipient;
        uint256 value;
    }

    // id => creator
    mapping (uint256 => address) public creators;
    // id => fees
    mapping (uint256 => Fee[]) public fees;

    constructor(string memory contractURI, string memory tokenURIPrefix) HasContractURI(contractURI) ERC1155Metadata_URI(tokenURIPrefix) public {

    }

    function getFeeRecipients(uint256 id) public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        Fee[] memory _fees = fees[id];
        address payable[] memory result = new address payable[](_fees.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _fees.length; i++) {
            result[i] = _fees[i].recipient;
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getFeeBps(uint256 id) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        Fee[] memory _fees = fees[id];
        uint[] memory result = new uint[](_fees.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _fees.length; i++) {
            result[i] = _fees[i].value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Creates a new token type and assings _initialSupply to minter
    function _mint(uint256 _id, Fee[] memory _fees, uint256 _supply, string memory _uri) internal {
        require(creators[_id] == address(0x0), "Token is already minted");
        require(_supply != 0, "Supply should be positive");
        require(bytes(_uri).length > 0, "uri should be set");

        creators[_id] = msg.sender;
        address[] memory recipients = new address[](_fees.length);
        uint[] memory bps = new uint[](_fees.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _fees.length; i++) {
            require(_fees[i].recipient != address(0x0), "Recipient should be present");
            require(_fees[i].value != 0, "Fee value should be positive");
            fees[_id].push(_fees[i]);
            recipients[i] = _fees[i].recipient;
            bps[i] = _fees[i].value;
        }
        if (_fees.length > 0) {
            emit SecondarySaleFees(_id, recipients, bps);
        }
        balances[_id][msg.sender] = _supply;
        _setTokenURI(_id, _uri);

        // Transfer event with mint semantic
        emit TransferSingle(msg.sender, address(0x0), msg.sender, _id, _supply);
        emit URI(_uri, _id);
    }

    function burn(address _owner, uint256 _id, uint256 _value) external {

        require(_owner == msg.sender || operatorApproval[_owner][msg.sender] == true, "Need operator approval for 3rd party burns.");

        // SafeMath will throw with insuficient funds _owner
        // or if _id is not valid (balance will be 0)
        balances[_id][_owner] = balances[_id][_owner].sub(_value);

        // MUST emit event
        emit TransferSingle(msg.sender, _owner, address(0x0), _id, _value);
    }

   
    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory uri) internal {
        require(creators[tokenId] != address(0x0), "_setTokenURI: Token should exist");
        super._setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    function setTokenURIPrefix(string memory tokenURIPrefix) public onlyOwner {
        _setTokenURIPrefix(tokenURIPrefix);
    }

    function setContractURI(string memory contractURI) public onlyOwner {
        _setContractURI(contractURI);
    }
}

/**
 * @title Roles
 * @dev Library for managing addresses assigned to a Role.
 */
library Roles {
    struct Role {
        mapping (address => bool) bearer;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Give an account access to this role.
     */
    function add(Role storage role, address account) internal {
        require(!has(role, account), "Roles: account already has role");
        role.bearer[account] = true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Remove an account's access to this role.
     */
    function remove(Role storage role, address account) internal {
        require(has(role, account), "Roles: account does not have role");
        role.bearer[account] = false;
    }

   
    function has(Role storage role, address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        require(account != address(0), "Roles: account is the zero address");
        return role.bearer[account];
    }
}

contract SignerRole is Context {
    using Roles for Roles.Role;

    event SignerAdded(address indexed account);
    event SignerRemoved(address indexed account);

    Roles.Role private _signers;

    constructor () internal {
        _addSigner(_msgSender());
    }

    modifier onlySigner() {
        require(isSigner(_msgSender()), "SignerRole: caller does not have the Signer role");
        _;
    }

    function isSigner(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _signers.has(account);
    }

    function addSigner(address account) public onlySigner {
        _addSigner(account);
    }

    function renounceSigner() public {
        _removeSigner(_msgSender());
    }

    function _addSigner(address account) internal {
        _signers.add(account);
        emit SignerAdded(account);
    }

    function _removeSigner(address account) internal {
        _signers.remove(account);
        emit SignerRemoved(account);
    }
}






contract RaribleToken is Ownable, SignerRole, ERC1155Base {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, address signer, string memory contractURI, string memory tokenURIPrefix) ERC1155Base(contractURI, tokenURIPrefix) public {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;

        _addSigner(signer);
        _registerInterface(bytes4(keccak256('MINT_WITH_ADDRESS')));
    }

    function addSigner(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _addSigner(account);
    }

    function removeSigner(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _removeSigner(account);
    }

    function mint(uint256 id, Fee[] memory fees, uint256 supply, string memory uri) onlyOwner public {
    
        _mint(id, fees, supply, uri);
    }
}



contract RaribleUserToken is RaribleToken {
    event CreateERC1155_v1(address indexed creator, string name, string symbol);

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory contractURI, string memory tokenURIPrefix, address signer) RaribleToken(name, symbol, signer, contractURI, tokenURIPrefix) public {
        emit CreateERC1155_v1(msg.sender, name, symbol);
    }

  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Fee` is of type struct-

```
struct Fee {
    address payable recipient;
    uint256 value;
}
```

And `mint` expects an array of `Fee` objects... try constructing your Fee argument like this?

```
[
    {
        "recipient": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
        "value": 34
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it using "[" brackets instead of regular brackets "(" for wrapping a struct.
So if you have arrays of tuple like (string, bool) then send data like:

```
[["firstTuple", true], ["secondTuple", false]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it with this using double brackets, example:

you have:

```bash
[
    {
        "recipient": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
        "value": 34
    }
]
```

use it this way in `Remix`:

```bash
[["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", 34]]
```

and it will work for you!